# Expandable List Android Black background while scrolling

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I'm struggling with the ExpandableList View in Android.
I'm using the code provided in the apis demo but I don't know how to solve my problem.

I got a white background on my view but when I'm scrolling the list it turns black..why?

I don't want this effect...is there a way to change it? is there a way to customize the list using this code? 
I'm looking for something like this..Hope you could help me!
Thank you :)

```
package com.example.android.apis.view;

import android.R;
import android.app.ExpandableListActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ExpandableListAdapter;
import android.widget.SimpleExpandableListAdapter;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;


/**
 * Demonstrates expandable lists backed by a Simple Map-based adapter
 */
public class ExpandableList3 extends ExpandableListActivity {
    private static final String NAME = "NAME";
    private static final String IS_EVEN = "IS_EVEN";

    private ExpandableListAdapter mAdapter;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        List<Map<String, String>> groupData = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
        List<List<Map<String, String>>> childData = new ArrayList<List<Map<String, String>>>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            Map<String, String> curGroupMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
            groupData.add(curGroupMap);
            curGroupMap.put(NAME, "Group " + i);
            curGroupMap.put(IS_EVEN, (i % 2 == 0) ? "This group is even" : "This group is odd");

            List<Map<String, String>> children = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
            for (int j = 0; j < 15; j++) {
                Map<String, String> curChildMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
                children.add(curChildMap);
                curChildMap.put(NAME, "Child " + j);
                curChildMap.put(IS_EVEN, (j % 2 == 0) ? "This child is even" : "This child is odd");
            }
            childData.add(children);
        }

        // Set up our adapter

        mAdapter = new SimpleExpandableListAdapter(
                this,
                groupData,
                android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1,
                new String[] { NAME, IS_EVEN },
                new int[] { android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2 },
                childData,
                R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_3,
                new String[] { NAME, IS_EVEN },
                new int[] { android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2 }
                );

        setListAdapter(mAdapter);
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you provide your layout code? Have you changed the background color of your listview?

Comment: show your xml file that contains <listview ..../>

Comment: i have just a linearlayout in my xml..no listview..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add to your listview in the xml file:

`android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"`

or in your Java code:

`getListView().setCacheColorHint(0);`

Comment: Thank you very much!! I need this getListView().setCacheColorHint(0); btw thank you everybody for ur answers ;)

Answer (score 5):

add  `android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"` to ListView

example;

```
<ListView
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:id="@+id/list"
   android:cacheColorHint="#00000000" />
```

Answer (score 2):

Write this one in your xml you will get the answer

android:scrollingCache="false"

Answer (score 1):

Follow the instructions on this link:

[Android Developer Ressources: Listview Backgrounds](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/listview-backgrounds.html)

In short:
...To fix this issue, all you have to do is either disable the cache color hint optimization, if you use a non-solid color background, or set the hint to the appropriate solid color value. You can do this from code (see setCacheColorHint(int)) or preferably from XML, by using the android:cacheColorHint attribute. To disable the optimization, simply use the transparent color #00000000. The following screenshot shows a list with android:cacheColorHint="#00000000" set in the XML layout file ...

Answer (score 0):

I'd just like to point out that there's a more elegant way of expressing `#00000000`, just use: `@android/color/transparent`. It's easier to understand if you come back to that code some time later (Yeah, I know that it's just an ARGB number anyway ;-)).

Answer (score 0):

Simply set your list color, using the methods below:

```
android:cacheColorHint="#000000"
```

or in your Java code:

```
listView.setCacheColorHint(0);
```